# Is there any good Redis dissector for Wireshark?

Tags: lua, redis, wireshark, wireshark-dissector

all:
Is there any good Redis dissector for Wireshark? I have used this: https://github.com/jzwinck/redis-wireshark, but it seems some error in dissectoring.
Thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the author of the Wireshark plugin for Redis mentioned in the OP.  I think its main issue is exactly what you reported here: https://github.com/jzwinck/redis-wireshark/issues/1 - namely that it doesn't reassemble TCP fragments.  I'm not currently using the plugin myself, but if you or someone else would contribute a patch to improve it I would gladly take it.

Comment: OK, I will try to enhance it！ Thanks for your answer!